# Finding angle of projectile given a distance (with air friction)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

[image]

So, I'm making a game. The game has archer in it. Arrows are simulated in 2D, $(x,y)$

An archer acquires a target and needs to know at what angle he needs to tilt his bow for the arrow to land at the target.

variables:

$t =$ time
$a =$ angle

The following constants are known:

$V_{0} =$ velocity, the initial velocity of the projectile.
$H =$ the initial height of the archer
$G =$ Gravity
$L =$ the distance to the target
$F =$ A simplified air friction constant.
$V$ (velocity) $=$ $V_{0} - F t$

I'm looking for $a$, the angle of the bow.

I know that $V_{x} = \cos(a)$ and $V_{y} = \sin(a)$

I know that:
$V_{x} \cdot t - 0.5 \cdot F \cdot t^{2} = L$

I know that:
$t = \frac{V_{y} + \sqrt{V_{y}^{2} + 2 \cdot G H}}{G}$

Which gives me these functions:

```
public static double length(double height, double angle, double velocity) {
        
    double vz = Math.sin(angle*2*Math.PI)*velocity;
    double v = Math.cos(angle*2*Math.PI)*velocity;
    double t = getTime(height, vz);
    return getLength(v, t);
}
    
public static double getTime(double height, double vz) {
    return (vz + Math.sqrt(vz*vz + 2*G*height))/G;
}
    
public static double getLength(double v, double time) {
    return time*v - 0.5*FRICTION*time*time;
}
```

This allows me for testing angles, and they work. In fact, my only solution right now is to test for the correct angle by binary search. It usually get a solution with 10-15 iterations.

There are many solutions for this without air friction, but I'm looking for one with it included.

However, I can't manage to substitute t and solve for $a$.

Comment: Wiki is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance

Comment: Does not answer the question. It does not have a solution for an angle with air friction. It has some reasoning with air friction, but this is advanced friction, while I am fine to simplify mine to a constant

Answer (score 1):

Starting with :

$$m\,\ddot x=-F\\
m\,\ddot y=-m\,g$$

and
$$x(0)=0~,\dot x(0)=v\,\cos(\alpha)\\
y(0)=h~,\dot y(0)=v\,\sin(\alpha)$$

you obtain  the solutions

$$x(t)=-\frac 12\,{\frac {F{t}^{2}}{m}}+v\cos \left( \alpha \right) t\tag 1$$
$$y(t)=-\frac 12\,g{t}^{2}+v\sin \left( \alpha \right) t+h\tag 2$$

with $~x(t)=L~$ you obtain the time $~t_L~$ that the projectile reach the distance L. substitute this time in equation (2)
$$y(t=t_L) =0=f(\alpha)$$
from the solution $~f(\alpha)=0~$  you obtain $~\alpha~$

---

$$f(\alpha)=-\frac 12\,{\frac {g \left( v\cos \left( \alpha \right) m-\sqrt {{v}^{2}
 \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}{m}^{2}-2\,FLm}
 \right) ^{2}}{{F}^{2}}}+{\frac {v\sin \left( \alpha \right)  \left( v
\cos \left( \alpha \right) m-\sqrt {{v}^{2} \left( \cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{m}^{2}-2\,FLm} \right) }{F}}+h
$$

Remarks:

the start velocity $~v~$ must be greater then
$ ~{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {F\,L\,m}}{m}}~$ otherwise you don't obtain real solution for the angle

**Edit**

numerical solution  $~f(\alpha)=0~$with Newton method

$$\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n-\frac{f(\alpha_n}{f'(\alpha_n)}$$

Example

Data=[F= 0.1,L=20,m=1,g=10,v=15,h=2]

$$n=0,\alpha_1=0+\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}=0.346~,f(\alpha_1)=-0.888\\\\
n=1~,\alpha_2=0.404~,f(\alpha_2)=-0.02\\
n=2~,\alpha_3=0.406~,f(\alpha_3)=-0.00001$$

so you need 2 interation to obtain the solution

Comment: Thank you Eli. Forgive my ignorance, but I need to solve this for α. I.E α =equation of other stuff, so α must be factored out and put on the left hand side. I tried doing this with wolframalpha and it couldn't do it.

Comment: The analytical solution is not useful because you have more then one solution , instead put all the data und solve for $\alpha$ I use Maple fsolve